# How can I make a chat room that sends the messages to an email address

Tags: php, css, email, chat

So a friend of mine asked me if I could help him make a chat room that sends the messages directly to his email. I accepted as it had been a project of mine to make a chat room for a while, but I have no idea how to do that, or how to have each message be sent to his email. I'm currently learning JavaScript, HTML, and CSS for courses needed for college, and he sent me his code. It's written in PHP, and while I understand most of it, I have no idea how PHP works or what to do with it. Could someone help? Code can be provided upon asking ^-^

Comment: Your question is so broad there’s no way to answer whatever your question is. Questions need to be about a specific, reproducible problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can send emails in many different ways with php.

Most simple is the php email function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), however it's not working often.

I'd recommend to read documentation of something like PHPMailer (it can send up to 100 mails pretty fast) https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

It should help you a bit, you can setup some class that'll send emails on call and then call this class later on in your code, so you don't have to repeat the whole PHPMailer code.